# Division by 10 having no effect in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was just debugging the plugin particles.js and came across the following likes of code:

```
this.parallaxTargX = (pointerX - (winW / 2)) / (options.parallaxMultiplier * this.layer);
this.parallaxOffsetX += (this.parallaxTargX - this.parallaxOffsetX) / 10; // Easing equation
```

These lines of code can be seen **[HERE](https://github.com/jnicol/particleground/blob/master/jquery.particleground.js#L279)** too.

If i add a breakpoints to line 280 , and console:

```
this.parallaxOffsetX += (this.parallaxTargX - this.parallaxOffsetX)
```

I get `3.466666666666667` , and if i `console.log` :

```
this.parallaxOffsetX += (this.parallaxTargX - this.parallaxOffsetX) / 10
```

I get `3.466666666666667` , Why is the division by 10 having no effect ?

Comment: Probably `(this.parallaxTargX - this.parallaxOffsetX)` is having a value of `0`?

Comment: having the values of the properties you are looking at would be very helpful - FYI

Answer (score 0):

If

```
this.parallaxTargX - this.parallaxOffsetX
```

is small enough (0 for example), then adding it to

```
this.parallaxOffsetX
```

is the same as adding 1/10 of it.